# navigating through firestore JSON object

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have an firestore object like this:

```
Object { name: "John", lastName: "Novak", frequency: 0.8, phone: "123123123", email: "something@gmail.com" }
```

I am using this function to get the object and I successfully write it in console

```
ocRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

The question: How do I navigate to and store only one property, for example`name`?

Comment: nevermind, I just found out I should use doc.data().name

Comment: If you've solved the issue, you can answer your own question, or simply delete the question altogether.